# Как исправить сортировку буквы "Ё" в TreeSet?

Tags: java, android, сортировка

В проекте нужно получить алфавитный указатель - отсортированный список букв. Для этого использую TreeSet. Но с ним есть проблема: он некорректно сортирует букву "Ё", она всегда встает в начало списка. Как я понимаю, это происходит из-за сравнения по коду символа и у буквы "Ё" он меньше, чем у буквы "А". Как правильно исправить эту проблему? Писать собственный компаратор?

Comment: В джаве операции со строками работают по умолчанию с локалью ОС.  У вас, видимо, в настройках ОС стоит нерусская локаль.  Но можно не зависеть от настроек ОС, напр, сравнивать слова так: `Collator.getInstance(new Locale("ru","RU")).compare(word1, word2)`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по таблице юникода у `Ё` код `U+0401` а у `ё` `U+0451`, причем остальной алфавит находится между ними, поэтому `Ё` всегда будет в начале а `ё` в конце.

Я бы рекомендовал для сортировки заменять `Ё` на `Е`, не или писать свой компаратор.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
Set<String> alphabet = new TreeSet<String>(new Comparator<String>() {
        private String letters = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";

        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            int lp = letters.indexOf(lhs);
            int rp = letters.indexOf(rhs);
            if (lp != -1 && rp != -1) {
                return new Integer(lp).compareTo(rp);
            }
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });
```